# Set @JoinColumn name in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**EDIT:**

In the end as @Jakumi commented it was just a cache issue, after clearing it everything worked as expected.

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and  naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

---

In the project I'm working on we use doctrine as ORM only meaning we don't use doctrine migrations.
I'm trying to map a column (from an existing table) which has a OneToMany association like this:

```php
    /**
     * @var InternalUser
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\InternalUser", inversedBy="blocos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="owner")
     */
    private $owner;
```

The problem is the column name is only `owner` not `owner_id` but when querying the database, using `->find('id')` for example, doctrine appends an `_id` suffix to the column name, generating a query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT .... t0.owner_id AS owner_id_6 FROM ...
```

And when the query is executed I get a `Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.owner_id does not exist` because the right name is just 'owner'.

I've tried setting both `name` and `referencedColumnName` to `"owner"` in the @JoinColumn annotation but it appends the `_id` suffix anyway.

I've also looked at [naming strategies](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/namingstrategy.html) but it doesn't seem to be responsible for the `_id` suffix (I'm using the default `UnderscoreNamingStrategy` that comes with symfony4)

Is there anyway to configure doctrine to **not** add the '_id' suffix?

PS:
Changing the column name is not an option

Comment: `name` is precisely the right parameter/attribute to set. do you by any chance work on prod and haven't cleared the cache?

Comment: You're right... It was a cache issue :(

Answer (score 0):

`name` is exactly for that, when you use it, doctrine should map correctly.

Now, what it seems awkward here is that you mentioned `->find('id')`.

If you have table **A**, and you desire to look something based on the `id` of that table is when you use `->find($id)`, it will look for the id of that table.

But you are talking of a relation, in which case you should use `findBy(['field' => $value])` or `findOneBy(['field' => $value])`.

I hoe this help, if not, can you show the exact query you are using and both side of the relation?